# PERL Email::Send::Gmail Cannot connect to Gmail account on Windows 7

Tags: perl, email

I am trying to use [`Email::Send::Gmail`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email%3a%3aSend%3a%3aGmail) to send an email, but for some reason I am getting an error that it is not allowing me to connect.

The code is the standard example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Send;
use Email::Send::Gmail;
use Email::Simple::Creator;

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
header => [
    From    => 'myaddress@gmail.com',
    To      => 'myaddress@gmail.com',
    Subject => 'Server down',
],
body => 'The server is down. Start panicing.',
);

my $sender = Email::Send->new(
{   mailer      => 'Gmail',
    mailer_args => [
        username => 'myaddress@gmail.com',
        password => 'XXXX',
    ]
}
);
eval { $sender->send($email) };
die "Error sending email: $@" if $@;
```

Exact Error is:

```
Email::Send::Gmail: error connecting to server smtp.gmail.com 
at C:/Perl/site/lib/Email/Send.pm line 256.
```

I've looked around my gmail account and there doesn't seem to be anything there to "allow access".  I'm on Windows7 and running from the command line.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
A

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en What's the result of these troubleshooting steps?

Comment: That can't be the complete error message.  Are you sure there are no additional messages describing the error?

Comment: "error connecting to server" suggests that a ping might be in order...

Comment: that's all im getting back on the command line, and if im pinging something, it's just going to be smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Did you ping it successfully?

Comment: i can ping smtp.gmail.com fine, yes

Comment: ...and ive gone through all the troubleshooting steps at support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Comment: By default SMTP uses port 25. What happens if you try to telnet to smtp.gmail.com on port 25? If that doesn't connect then you're probably running into some kind of firewall issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on strawberry perl 5.18.2.  Will chime in with a solution if I find one.

Comment: Turned off my local firewall, still no luck.  I'm at home so there's no other firewall.

Comment: going to try the port 25 suggestion

Comment: telnet to smtp.gmail.com 25 connected fine

Comment: ... i did notice if i leave out the "25" it by default is trying to connect on port "23".  Should i be defining my port in the code maybe?

Comment: @user3050186 - port 23 is telnet. Port 25 is mail. I'm pretty sure underlying mail code already uses 25, unless it's a really broken module that never worked

Comment: any other ideas here guys?... still cannot connect, but no problem pinging server :(

Comment: See below for the fix from Miller... I reinstalled IO::Socket::SSL and it resolved the issue.  Epic help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time to upgrade your dependencies.

[`Email::Gmail::Send`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email%3a%3aSend%3a%3aGmail) depends on [`Net::SMTP::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSMTP%3a%3aSSL) which depends on [`IO::Socket::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSSL).  The first step I take to solving this type of problem is to upgrade the module dependencies just in case a new issue has already been addressed.

Unfortunately, 4 Days ago when you first introduced this problem, I was unable to pass the test suite for `IO::Socket::SSL 1.986` on `Strawberry Perl 5.18.2`.

```
t/public_suffix_lib_uri.t ......... ok
failed to connect: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. at t/public_suffix_ssl.t line 87.
# Looks like you planned 24 tests but ran 2.
# Looks like your test exited with 10038 just after 2.
```

Fortunately, since then the author has updated the module to `IO::Socket::SSL 1.988`, and I'm able to fully install and use it on both Windows 7 and Linux.  Currently it throws redefined warnings ([`cpan ticket 95881`](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=95881)), but I was able to send Gmail messages on Windows after upgrading this dependency.

Note: You'll want to create an [`application specific password`](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for this code, otherwise Gmail might block the login and send you a "Suspicious sign in prevented" email.

Comment: Mr Miller, I would like to buy you a Miller!! That upgrade to the latest version of IO::Socket::SSL fixed the problem.  Connection established and emails sending via gmail.

Answer (score 0):

> Just Upgrade your active Perl version.

**Then Install following modules:**
ppm

1. install Email::send:Gmail
2. install Net::SMTP:SSL
3. installIO::socket::SSL

---

## Then try with below sample code.

```
 #!/home/ben/software/install/bin/perl
        use warnings;
        use strict;
        use Email::Send;
    use Email::Send::Gmail;
    use Email::Simple::Creator;

    my $email = Email::Simple->create (
        header => [
            From    => '@gmail.com',
                To      => '@gmail.com',
                Subject => 'Make it simple',
        ],

        body => 'buddy I got it ...',
    );

    my $sender = Email::Send->new 
    ({
            mailer      => 'Gmail',
            mailer_args => 
[
                username => '',
                password => '',
        ]
    });

    $sender->send ($email);
```